# Is there a way to call Angular Controller function from Javascript written inside <Script> tag in the HTML Page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We are working on an application which is functional on angularjs but we decided to use Syncfusion toolbar . We decided to go with Javascript ribbon which is responsive as we had angular option as well. Now the concern is that We want to use the code already written in controller class but that is not accessible from the function neither can i bind the event to the controllers method. Please suggest what can be the best way to achieve the functionality.

Sample is as:

HTML Codes script tag is like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fontfamily = ["Noto Sans", "Arial", "Times New Roman", "Tahoma", "Helvetica"], fontsize = ["1pt", "2pt", "3pt", "4pt", "5pt"], action1 = ["New", "Clear"], action2 = ["Bold", "Italic", "Underline", "strikethrough", "superscript", "subscript", "JustifyLeft", "JustifyCenter", "JustifyRight", "JustifyFull", "Undo", "Redo"];
    $(function () {

        $("#defaultRibbon").ejRibbon({
            width: "100%",
            expandPinSettings:{
                toolTip: "Collapse the Ribbon"

            },
            collapsePinSettings:{
                toolTip: "Pin the Ribbon"

            },
            allowResizing:true,
            applicationTab: { type: ej.Ribbon.ApplicationTabType.Menu, menuItemID: "ribbonmenu", menuSettings: { openOnClick: false } },
            tabs: [{
                id: "home", text: "HOME", groups: [{
                    text: "New", alignType: ej.Ribbon.AlignType.Rows, content: [{
                        groups: [{
                            id: "new",
                            text: "New",
                            toolTip: "New",
                            isMobileOnly: true,
                            buttonSettings: {
                                contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,
                                imagePosition: ej.ImagePosition.ImageTop,
                                prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-ribbonnew",
                                click: "executeAction"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            id: "save",
                            text: "Save",
                            toolTip: "Save",
                            isMobileOnly: true,
                            buttonSettings: {
                                contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,
                                imagePosition: ej.ImagePosition.ImageTop,
                                prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-ribbonsave",
                                click: "executeAction"
                            }
                        }
                        ],
                        defaults: {
                            type: ej.Ribbon.Type.Button,
                            width: 50,
                            height: 52
                        }
                    }]
                },
                {
                    text: "Manage", alignType: ej.Ribbon.AlignType.Columns, content: [{
                        groups: [{
                            id: "edit",
                            text: "Edit",
                            toolTip: "Edit",
                            buttonSettings: {
                                contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,
                                imagePosition: ej.ImagePosition.ImageTop,
                                prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-ribbonedit",
                                click: "onEditClick"
                            }
                        }
                        ],
                        defaults: {
                            type: ej.Ribbon.Type.Button,
                            width: 50,
                            height: 52
                        }
                    },
                     {
                        groups: [{
                            id: "copy",
                            text: "Copy",
                            toolTip: "Copy",
                            buttonSettings: {
                                contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,                                    
                                prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-ribboncopy",
                                click: "executeAction"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            id: "delete",
                            text: "Delete",
                            toolTip: "Delete",
                            buttonSettings: {
                                contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,
                                prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-ribbondelete",
                                click: "executeAction"
                            }
                        }
                        ],
                        defaults: {
                            type: ej.Ribbon.Type.Button,
                            width: 60,
                            height: 26,
                            isBig: false
                        }
                    }]
                },
                {
                    text: "Change", alignType: ej.Ribbon.AlignType.Columns, content: [{
                        groups: [{
                            id: "refresh",
                            text: "Refresh",
                            toolTip: "Refresh",
                            buttonSettings: {
                                contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,
                                imagePosition: ej.ImagePosition.ImageTop,
                                prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-ribbonrefresh",
                                click: "executeAction"
                            }
                        }
                        ],
                        defaults: {
                            type: ej.Ribbon.Type.Button,
                            width: 50,
                            height: 52
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        groups: [{
                            id: "undo",
                            text: "Undo",
                            toolTip: "Undo",
                            buttonSettings: {
                                contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,
                                prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-ribbonundo",
                                click: "executeAction"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            id: "redo",
                            text: "Redo",
                            toolTip: "Redo",
                            buttonSettings: {
                                contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,
                                prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-ribbonredo",
                                click: "executeAction"
                            }
                        }],
                        defaults: {
                            type: ej.Ribbon.Type.Button,
                            width: 60,
                            height: 26,
                            isBig: false
                        }
                    }]
                },


                 {
                     text: "Views", alignType: ej.Ribbon.AlignType.Columns, content: [{

                         groups: [{
                             id: "listview",
                             text: "List View",
                             toolTip: "List         ",
                             buttonSettings: {
                                 contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,
                                 prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-ribbonlistview",
                                 click: "executeAction"
                             }
                         },
                         {
                             id: "cardview",
                             text: "Card View",
                             toolTip: "Card View",
                             buttonSettings: {
                                 contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,
                                 prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-ribbongridview",
                                 click: "executeAction"
                             }
                         }],
                         defaults: {
                             type: ej.Ribbon.Type.Button,
                             width: 90,
                             height: 26,
                             isBig: false
                         }
                     }]
                 },


                  {
                      text: "Navigation", alignType: ej.Ribbon.AlignType.Columns, content: [{
                          groups: [{
                              id: "first",
                              text: "First",
                              toolTip: "First",
                              buttonSettings: {
                                  contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,
                                  prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-ribbonfirst",
                                  click: "executeAction"
                              }
                          }, {
                              id: "previous",
                              text: "Previous",
                              toolTip: "Previous",
                              buttonSettings: {
                                  contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,
                                  prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-ribbonprevious",
                                  click: "executeAction"
                              }
                          }],
                          defaults: {
                              type: ej.Ribbon.Type.Button,
                              width: 70,
                              height: 26,
                              isBig: false
                          }
                      },
                      {
                          groups: [{
                              id: "last",
                              text: "Last",
                              toolTip: "Last",
                              buttonSettings: {
                                  contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,
                                  prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-ribbonlast",
                                  click: "executeAction"
                              }
                          },
                          {
                              id: "next",
                              text: "Next",
                              toolTip: "Next",
                              buttonSettings: {
                                  contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,
                                  prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-ribbonnext",
                                  click: "executeAction"
                              }
                          }],
                          defaults: {
                              type: ej.Ribbon.Type.Button,
                              width: 55,
                              height: 26,
                              isBig: false
                          }
                      }]
                  },
                {
                    text: "Print", alignType: ej.Ribbon.AlignType.Rows, content: [{
                        groups: [
                            { 
                                id: "printpreview",
                                text: "Preview",
                                toolTip: "Preview",
                                buttonSettings: {
                                    contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,
                                    imagePosition: ej.ImagePosition.ImageTop,
                                    prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-ribbonprintpreview",
                                    click: "executeAction"
                                }
                            },

                        {
                            id: "print",
                            text: "Print",
                            toolTip: "Print",
                            buttonSettings: {
                                contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,
                                imagePosition: ej.ImagePosition.ImageTop,
                                prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-ribbonprint",
                                click: "executeAction"
                            }
                        }
                        ],
                        defaults: {
                            type: ej.Ribbon.Type.Button,
                            width: 50,
                            height: 52
                        }
                    }]
                },

                {
                    text: "Import/ Export", alignType: ej.Ribbon.AlignType.Columns, content: [{
                        groups: [
                            {
                                id: "exportasexcel",
                                text: "Export as Excel",
                                toolTip: "Export as Excel",
                                buttonSettings: {
                                    contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,
                                    prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-ribbonexportasexcel",
                                    click: "executeAction"
                                }
                            },

                       {
                           id: "importasexcel",
                           text: "Import as Excel",
                           toolTip: "Import as Excel",
                           buttonSettings: {
                               contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,
                               prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-ribbonimportasexcel",
                               click: "executeAction"
                           }
                       }
                        ],
                        defaults: {
                            type: ej.Ribbon.Type.Button,
                            width: 110,
                            height: 26,
                            isBig: false
                        }
                    }]
                },
                {
                    text: "Favorites", alignType: ej.Ribbon.AlignType.Rows, content: [{
                        groups: [
                            {
                                id: "favorites",
                                text: "Favorites",
                                toolTip: "Favorites",
                                buttonSettings: {
                                    contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,
                                    imagePosition: ej.ImagePosition.ImageTop,
                                    prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-ribbonFavorites",
                                    click: "executeAction"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        defaults: {
                            type: ej.Ribbon.Type.Button,
                            width: 60,
                            height: 52
                        }
                    }]
                },
                 {
                     text: "Alerts", alignType: ej.Ribbon.AlignType.Rows, content: [{
                         groups: [
                             {
                                 id: "notification",
                                 text: "Notification",
                                 toolTip: "Notification",
                                 buttonSettings: {
                                     contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,
                                     imagePosition: ej.ImagePosition.ImageTop,
                                     prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-ribbonNotification",
                                     click: "executeAction"
                                 }
                             }
                         ],
                         defaults: {
                             type: ej.Ribbon.Type.Button,
                             width: 65,
                             height: 52
                         }
                     }]
                 },
                  {
                      text: "", alignType: ej.Ribbon.AlignType.Rows, content: [{
                          groups: [
                              {
                                  id: "find",
                                  text: "Find",
                                  toolTip: "Find",
                                  buttonSettings: {
                                      contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,
                                      imagePosition: ej.ImagePosition.ImageTop,
                                      prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-ribbonfind",
                                      click: "executeAction"
                                  }
                              }
                          ],
                          defaults: {
                              type: ej.Ribbon.Type.Button,
                              width: 60,
                              height: 52
                          }
                      }]
                  },

                   {
                       text: "", alignType: ej.Ribbon.AlignType.Rows, content: [{
                           groups: [
                               {
                                   id: "design",
                                   text: "Design",
                                   toolTip: "Design",
                                   buttonSettings: {
                                       contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,
                                       imagePosition: ej.ImagePosition.ImageTop,
                                       prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-ribbonDesign",
                                       click: "executeAction"
                                   }
                               }
                           ],
                           defaults: {
                               type: ej.Ribbon.Type.Button,
                               width: 60,
                               height: 52
                           }
                       }]
                   },


                    {
                        text: "", alignType: ej.Ribbon.AlignType.Columns, content: [{
                            groups: [
                                {
                                    id: "logout",
                                    text: "Logout",
                                    toolTip: "Logout",
                                    buttonSettings: {
                                        contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,
                                        imagePosition: ej.ImagePosition.ImageTop,
                                        prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-ribbonlogout",
                                        click: "executeAction"
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            defaults: {
                                type: ej.Ribbon.Type.Button,
                                width: 60,
                                height: 52
                            }
                        },

                        {
                            groups: [{
                                id: "preferences",
                                text: "Preferences",
                                toolTip: "Preferences",
                                buttonSettings: {
                                    contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,
                                    prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-ribbonpreferences",
                                    click: "executeAction"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                id: "help",
                                text: "Help",
                                toolTip: "Help",
                                buttonSettings: {
                                    contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,
                                    prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-ribbonhelp",
                                    click: "executeAction"
                                }
                            }
                            ],
                            defaults: {
                                type: ej.Ribbon.Type.Button,
                                width: 80,
                                isBig: false
                            }
                        }

                        ]
                    }




                //{
                //    text: "View", alignType: ej.Ribbon.AlignType.Rows, content: [{
                //        groups: [{
                //            id: "zoomin",
                //            text: "Zoom In",
                //            toolTip: "Zoom In",
                //          width: 58,
                //            buttonSettings: {
                //                contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,
                //                imagePosition: ej.ImagePosition.ImageTop,
                //                prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-zoomin",
                //                click: "executeAction"
                //            }
                //        },
                //          {
                //              id: "zoomout",
                //              text: "Zoom Out",
                //              toolTip: "Zoom Out",
                //              width: 70,
                //              buttonSettings: {
                //                  contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,
                //                  imagePosition: ej.ImagePosition.ImageTop,
                //                  prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-zoomout",
                //                  click: "executeAction"
                //              }
                //          },
                //          {
                //              id: "fullscreen",
                //              text: "Full Screen",
                //              toolTip: "Full Screen",
                //              width: 73,
                //              buttonSettings: {
                //                  contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,
                //                  imagePosition: ej.ImagePosition.ImageTop,
                //                  prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-fullscreen",
                //                  click: "executeAction"
                //              }
                //          }
                //        ],
                //        defaults: {
                //            type: ej.Ribbon.Type.Button,
                //            height: 70
                //        }
                //    }]
                //}]
                ]
            }

            ,
            {
                id: "actions", text: "ACTIONS", groups: [{
                    text: "Tables", alignType: ej.Ribbon.AlignType.Columns, content: [{
                        groups: [{
                            id: "tables",
                            text: "Tables",
                            isMobileOnly: true,
                            toolTip: "Tables",
                            buttonSettings: {
                                contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,
                                imagePosition: ej.ImagePosition.ImageTop,
                                prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-table",
                                click: "executeAction"
                            }
                        }
                        ],
                        defaults: {
                            type: ej.Ribbon.Type.Button,
                            width: 50,
                            height: 55
                        }
                    }]
                },
                {
                    text: "Save", alignType: ej.Ribbon.AlignType.Rows, content: [{
                        groups: [{
                            id: "print",
                            text: "Print",
                            toolTip: "Print",
                            buttonSettings: {
                                contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,
                                imagePosition: ej.ImagePosition.ImageTop,
                                prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-print",
                                click: "executeAction"
                            }
                        },
                            {
                                id: "save",
                                text: "Save",
                                toolTip: "Save",
                                buttonSettings: {
                                    contentType: ej.ContentType.TextAndImage,
                                    imagePosition: ej.ImagePosition.ImageTop,
                                    prefixIcon: "e-icon e-ribbon e-save",
                                    click: "executeAction"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        defaults: {
                            type: ej.Ribbon.Type.Button,
                            width: 50,
                            height: 55
                        }
                    }]
                }
                ]
            }

            ],
            create:"createControl"
        });
    });
```

and the controllers code is like this

```
function _controller($scope, $state, toolbarService, cxsToolbarButtons) {
    $scope.isShowNav = false;

    $scope.$watchCollection(toolbarService.getEnabledButtons, _updateButtons, true);

    $scope.toolboxButtons = [{
        id: cxsToolbarButtons.copy,
        enabled: false,
        icon: "icon-copy",
        onClick: _copy,
        title: "Copy"
    },{
        id: cxsToolbarButtons.edit,
        enabled: false,
        icon: "icon-edit",
        onClick: _edit,
        title: "Edit"
    }];



    function _edit() {
        $scope.notify(cxsToolbarButtons.edit);
    }
```

Is it possible to use the existing functions defined in controller via the Script in HTML page ?

Answer (score 0):

(if you read my previous answer, sorry, I read your question wrong)

What I'd suggest is to use a custom event on for instance the window object. At the location where you want your controller function to be called do something like this (using jQuery for this example)

```
<script>
    $(window).trigger('mySuperDuperEvent');
</script>
```

Then in your controller, listen for the event like this:

```
angular.module('app').controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $(window).on('mySuperDuperEvent', eventHandler);
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        $(window).off('mySuperDuperEvent', eventHandler);
    });

    function eventHandler() {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            // Handle event here!
        });
    }
});
```

Just keep the following in mind:

- Make sure to do your work in the eventhandler in a $scope.$apply() to make sure Angular runs a digest after it's done
- Make sure to remove the event handler when the controller is removed (by looking at the scope's $destroy event. Otherwise you'll create a slow memory leak by keeping the event handlers there forever.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially that long piece of code is DOM manipulation code. Directives/components are the part of Angular that deals with that. I would suggest putting the code inside a directive.

Then, in order for the suggested directive/component to have access to the controller function, simply hand over a reference to it. The directive/component can just call the function whenever it needs it. The end usage would be something in your template that looks like:

```
<ej-ribbon onsomething="yourFunction"></ej-ribbon>
```

Read more about [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and [components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) for a bit more detail.